# Getting started with Altera FPGAs

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga

I am getting a Cyclone II-based [Altera DE1](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&No=83) FPGA board to experiment with. I know a lot about programming, a bit about electronics and very little about FPGAs. What books or other resources would you recommend to someone like me to get started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~hamblen/book/bookse.htm) book is based on Altera hardware and development tools. You need the fourth edition for the DE1.

Comment: Will I be able to follow the book as a beginner with the [DE0 Nano](http://www.adafruit.com/products/451) ?